# Mock a function in a Python whl file

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-wheel

I'm trying to write a test for a function that calls a function in a `.whl` file, but I'm struggling to mock the function in the wheel. I have the wheel installed in my virtual environment - I installed the wheel with `pip install my_wheel.whl` while in the environment. The package that's in the wheel is called `my_package`.

The **function I want to test** looks something like this:

```
from my_package import wheel_function

def my_func():
   x = wheel_function()
   return x + 5
```

I want to mock `wheel_function` so the test just looks at `my_func`.

My **test script**:

```
import pytest

def mock_wheel_function():
    return 5

def test_my_func(mocker):
   my_mock = mocker.patch("src.wheels.my_wheel.path.to.wheel_function", 
                          side_effect=mock_wheel_function)
   # (Do stuff)
```

I get the following error: `AttributeError: module 'src.wheels' has no attribute 'my_wheel'`.

My directory structure is like this.

src 
|  wheels 
|........ my_wheel.whl 
| modules 
|........ my_module

tests 
| - test_modules 
|........ test_my_module

If I try to pass in the path to the module in the virtual environment (i.e. `/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/....`), I get `ModuleNotFoundError: module '/Users/me/venv/lib/python3' not found`.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Are `src` and `wheels` Python packages, or just directories? If `wheel_function` is contained in the module `my_package`, its import path will just be `my_package.wheel_function`.

Comment: `wheels` is just a directory. I think `src` is a directory that contains the package `modules`. When I create the wheel file (in the other directory), `setup.py` is located in that directory's `src`.

Comment: I think that worked! If you post that as an answer, I'll make it the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `mocker.patch`, you must provide the Python import path to the object you are mocking, not the relative filesystem path.

Since `wheel_function` is contained in the module `my_package`, you will want to setup your mocker as

```
my_mock = mocker.patch(
    "my_package.wheel_function", 
    side_effect=mock_wheel_function
)
```